# Do surface plasmon-polaritons travel in one direction or do they oscillate at the frequency of the photons that excite them?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, electrons, metals, plasmon

Sorry if this question doesn't make sense; this is way out of my field of study. From what I've read about SPP's, they seem to be oscillations in electron densities moving over the surface of a metal/dielectric interface in one direction. However, I was recently reading about their potential applications in nano rectennas (rectifying antennas) and I don't understand why a seemingly (to me) pulsating DC current would need to be rectified. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 'pulsating DC' is a bit of an oxymoron. But, both plasmons and polaritons have both an energy and a momentum, following the appropriate dispersion relations.

Comment: Thanks Jon. When I said 'pulsating DC' I just meant that the current moves intermittently in one direction (stopping and going) without reversing. Is this an accurate description?

Comment: Please elaborate on these "nano rectennas", their connection to the plasmon-polaritons and why there should be a pulsating dc current.

Comment: @freecharly Rectennas are just antennas connected to diodes in order to achieve a half-wave rectification of the current excited in the antenna by an em wave. In order to couple to visible light, the antennas must be made extremely small. From what I understand, the frequency of light is so high that the antennas must utilize SPP's in order to efficiently couple. From what I can tell, electrons only travel one way in SPP's so i'm confused as to why the current needs to be rectified. Maybe this video is confusing me. [SPP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJ8enHiq0H4). Thanks.

Comment: @James - I'll have a look at the video.

Comment: @James - In SPPs Electrons don't travel only in one direction. They oscillate in both directions like electrons in a wire with an ac current. In addition the charge density of the electrons also oscillates from positive to negative, etc.

Comment: @freecharly Awesome! Very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surface polaritons-plasmons (SPPs) are coupled oscillations of charge density and electromagnetic fields that can propagate as waves along the surface of two materials which have opposite signs of the real part their permittivity. Usually, in the considered frequency range, metals due to their electron plasma have a negative real part of permittivity and can be used together with a dielectric (air, etc.) to propagate these waves. These waves can be excited by light waves by appropriate couplers and usually have shorter  wavelengths at a given frequency than light waves in vacuum. These waves can be considered to be sinusoidal waves where the electric field, magnetic field, charge density and current (in the metal) oscillate sinusoidally. To convert light waves into usable electrical power, the induced electric current oscillations induced by the ac field of the light in minuscule antennas, together with e.g. rectifying metal-insulator-metal diodes, can be utilized to produce a dc current/voltage to generate usable electric power.